# Bootstrap Hamburger Menu Customizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav

I'm building a responsive hamburger dropdown with bootstrap and im having an issue with where the menu drops down when clicked. I would like the menu to appear under the logo, but it appears to the right of it (and on the same line.)

Here is my code [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNM3E.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>DeepRoot Productions</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <!--Navbar-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                <!--Logo-->
                    <div class="navbar-brand logo">
                        <p>DeepRoot Productions</p>
                    </div>
                <!--Hamburger Menu-->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!--Full-Width Navbar-->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a class="right-space" href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a class="right-space" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a class="right-space" href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `.navbar-header` class that wraps the `.navbar-brand` and the hamburger button like so:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
            <!--Logo-->
                <div class="navbar-brand logo">
                    <p>DeepRoot Productions</p>
                </div>
            <!--Hamburger Menu-->
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
            <!--Full-Width Navbar-->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a class="right-space" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="right-space" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a class="right-space" href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Here is a fiddle demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/ca9kdk4o/)

Comment: Thanks! That defiantly did it!

Comment: If you want them to only be centered at the mobile widths I updated the fiddle with a media query in the css so check out the fiddle and let me know it that is what you are looking for.